# askopenfiledialog to load many picke files and convert them to one Dataframe

Tags: python, pickle

I have one task to do and its pretty simple I guess but im a total newbie to python and visual studio code

I have like 10 pikled files and want to load them via the ask_opendialog, the I want to merge them to one big dataframe

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


root = Tk()  #Erzeugung eines Fensters
root.title("evalTool")
root.geometry("200x200")


def open():
    """Loads all the pkl_files and merges then into one dataframe"""    
                                                     
    df1 = filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=[('Python-files','.pkl')],      
                                    initialdir='C:/Python23', mode="r",
                                    multiple=True)
df1 = pd.read_pickle(df1,parse_dates=True)                                              

   
Button1 = Button(text="Load Files", width=70, command=open)
Button1.place(x=10, y=40, width=70, height=20)

root.mainloop()
```

thats what I have so far.

Comment: I came up with a solution:

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution:

```
def openfile():

    global df

    pickle_list = filedialog.askopenfilenames()
    print(pickle_list)
    for filename in pickle_list:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as pickle_file:
            df_new = pd.read_pickle(filename)
            df.append(df_new)

    df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```